# Qt Installation not working

Tags: c++, windows, qt, installation

As far as I know there are trillions of questions like mine, yet I haven't found a solution yet.

So, here's my problem: I've installed Qt 5.4 downloading the 2 packages from http://download.qt.io/official_releases/.

The packages I've downloaded are:

- qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64-5.4.0
- qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw491_opengl-5.4.0

because I'm working on a bloody Windows 8.1.

Now, the installation seemed to be working fine, and as soon as the process has ended I rushed to my Desktop folder and tried the ordinary "HelloWorld" application.

I tried to type in cmd "mingw32-make" and it outputed `C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\hellllllo\main.cpp:1: error: QtWidgets: No such file or directory #include < QtWidgets>`.

What strikes me is the fact that some Qt examples provided in the installation work fine, some others not. Please, give me a hint or a path to follow  to set up Qt! Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've also tried countless times to change variable PATH, but with no result.

Comment: Well, that's all folks! I've just installed ubuntu NOT alongside w8.1 and in less than 10 min I've launched my first QtApp ;) thanks Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If `qmake` is not found, then PATH is incorrect.
2. Regarding include's, the easiest way is to create qt.conf file. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html

P.S. Sample qt.conf

```
[Paths]
Prefix=..
Headers=include/qt5
```

Comment: 1. I try to explain it better: I've installed Qt 5.4 in "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0MinGw", so, I've edited the PATH as "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0MinGw\5.4\mingw491_32\bin" ... 2 Where should I put a qt.conf file? and moreover, what should I write in it? thanks!

Comment: @Foga But where's `qmake.exe`? Could you just find it on the drive?

Comment: @Foga qt.conf should contain at least [Paths] and Prefix=<dir> lines as in docs. 'Prefix' is Qt's root directory, probably "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0MinGw".

Comment: I've carried out an extensive search for "qmake.exe", and I found 2 "qmake.exe" (this is because I've installed 2 packages of qt) and one of them is inside the path mentioned before..

Comment: `qmake` itself is only dependent upon C runtime, but not Qt libraries. If both `qmake.exe` and mingw runtime dll's (such as libstdc++) are on PATH, it *must* work.

Comment: @ user4419802 I tried to type in cmd "qmake -project" -> ok; "qmake hello" -> ok, but when I try "make" -> make is not recognized as a internal command; so I tried "mingw32-make" -> fatal error: QtWidgets: No such file or directory #include <QtWidgets>

Comment: @Foga So `qmake` is OK. Then create qt.conf in the directory where qmake is.

Comment: Should it work like "[Paths]
Prefix = C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0MinGw\5.4\mingw491_32\lib" ??

Comment: Prefix is Qt *root* directory, such as C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0MinGw\5.4 Thus, libraries should become like %Prefix%\lib, headers - %Prefix%\include etc. Read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71397/discussion-between-foga-and-user4419802).